# Как правильно отправить ajax запрос?

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii

В Yii2 во вьюшке account/vies/index.php при клике на кнопку должен отправляться пробный ajax-запрос на файл, который лежит в той же папке

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

function request(){
    url = 'interface.php'
    ajax.onreadystatechange = response
    ajax.open('POST', url, true)
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    ajax.send('name=me&msg=mymsg&time=2019')

}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/account/interface.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Помогите разобраться, как правильно отправить этот запрос на сервер?

Answer (score 2):

Все запросы, в том числе и ajax отправляются на action контроллера. На конкретный файл (не в директории web) запрос отправить не получится. В данном случае надо отправлять запрос на `/account/interface`, а в контроллере `AccountController` создать метод `actionInterface`.

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    // ...
    public function actionInterface(){
        // response
    }
}
```

При отправке POST-запроса на action контроллера, также необходимо отправлять csrf токен.
Получить токен можно так:

```
$csrfToken = Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken();
```

Отключить эту проверку **(не рекомендуется)** в контроллере можно следующим образом:

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, если отправляю на action контроллера, то выпадает ошибка POST http://localhost:8080/account/interface 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: А этот адрес доступен? Если в браузере набрать, ответ приходит?

Comment: Адрес доступен, и вьюшка под нее выводится.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. С пост-запросом не все так просто.